# Best software to do big number calculations quickly

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, c++, software, computer-arithmetic

I am trying to do some work on some math conjecture. I am testing the conjecture numbers using very large math numbers (100+ digits ). I am currently using python to test these numbers.

In the conjecture's calculation, I quickly need to multiply and divide different large numbers several times. Python can do this quickly(~3000 calculations per minute). Is there any other faster software to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried any of the various GMP bindings for Python?At least at one point in the past that could [lead to large speedups](https://jasonstitt.com/c-extension-n-choose-k).

Comment: Are the numbers integers?

Comment: yes,numbers are intergers

Comment: You can probably use SymEngine, it is written in C++ but can be used as a Python library.

Comment: Boost.Multiprecision? It has GMP bindings if you need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not give [GMPY2](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) a try? From the introduction:

> gmpy2 is a C-coded Python extension module that supports multiple-precision arithmetic. gmpy2 is the successor to the original gmpy module. The gmpy module only supported the GMP multiple-precision library. gmpy2 adds support for the MPFR (correctly rounded real floating-point arithmetic) and MPC (correctly rounded complex floating-point arithmetic) libraries. gmpy2 also updates the API and naming conventions to be more consistent and support the additional functionality.

GMPY2 supports the integer arithmetic I assume you need and I doubt you can find anything faster.

On *nix based systems, you'll need to make sure that the latest version of GMP is installed ([GNU MP Bignum Library](https://gmplib.org/). On Windows, you can find a Python wheel courtesy of Christophe Gohlke [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gmpy).

Answer (score 1):

Using something such as [`numpy.divide`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html), you most likely will see no considerable difference from doing it in C++. Although casting might be something to consider. 
C++ may see some improvement in this area as Python will have to deal with this in real-time. With C++ this will not pose an issue. 
(Python will now cast any `ints` to `floats` for doing division as well).

Answer (score 1):

OP's comment on OP:

> yes,numbers are intergers

For arbitrarily large integer calculations, MAPLE is an option worth trying. it has very efficient implementations for a number of such calculations.